# Encrypt a Excel (v14) file on a Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a folder, then use Disk Utility to encrypt the folder.
Create the folder, put your Excel file in it.
Open Disk Utility. (In the Utilities folder inside the Applications folder.)

1. In the File menu, select New, then New Disk Image from Folder.
2. Navigate to the desired folder, then click Image.
3. Choose a name and save location for your disk image. Note the two pull-down options: Image Format and Encryption.
4. If you’re going to transfer your disk image (for example, on a flash drive), select Compressed under the Image Format pull-down.
5. To add password protection, select 128-bit or 256-bit AES encryption under the Encryption pull-down.
6. Click Save, and Disk Utility creates the new disk image.
7. A password pop-up appears.
8. Enter and verify the password of your choice.